# What is best way for thread to iterate over dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary, thread-safety

I want to create server mechanism where clients would add key/value pairs to the concurrent dictionary on the server and separate thread which would iterate through this dictionary all the time, collect keys (Guids) and call external API. Something like this:

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, EventResponse> EventDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, EventResponse>();
```

EventResponse can be Passed, Failed or Waiting.

API method:

```
public EventResponse APICall(Guid key)
```

Different client method would check response from the dictionary and after getting Passed or Failed, it would remove key/value pair for its guid and return result to the client.

I need help with implementation of the thread which would constantly iterate through dictionary and call external API. Please note that clients will add keys/values to this dictionary constantly. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose a dictionary as opposed to a queue structure? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why a ConcurrentDictionary or why use the same structure? ConcurrentDictionary doesn't implement the IProducerConsumerCollection<T> that purpose-built for this scenario. Eg, why not add tuples to a BlockingCollection?

Comment: Yes, from your description a `ConcurrentDictionary` doesn't seem the best solution.

Comment: Well, I wanted collection where different client would store their request (guid) and later they would check for their result by pinging in some period of time. As I describes, I need implementation of a thread which would provide these results from API. I am not much experienced, so any advise helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Cemsha I don't think you are implementing this the correct way but to answer your question, you should add a mutex or critical section when accessing the dictionary (both the client and server) that will block attempts from other side to change/read dictionary. On the server side you would then call ToList() to get a copy for iterating and then release the mutex.